# Can't boot Scientific Linux

Tags: boot, windows, system-installation, dual-boot, scientific-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot boot Linux Mint after installing Windows (First) and Linux Mint (Second)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41170/cannot-boot-linux-mint-after-installing-windows-first-and-linux-mint-second)

I have installed Scientific Linux on my Asus laptop where I already have installed Windows 7. Everything went alright and after installation I rebooted my system and to my surprise there was not boot loader (for OS choosing) like that of GRUB and so my system initiated normally into the Windows 7 OS. I rebooted again and pressed the F10 to load the booting menu but I can only choose from Windows Booting Option or P2 Disk option.

Can someone give me a solution to solve my problem and boot into my newly installed scientific Linux? Is it possible to install another boot loader that's not the one that "apparently" came with the SL installation disk? If so how? If not, any suggestions?

Further info: - Tried using SL installation CD to update boot loader. Didn't help - Tried using " " " change boot loader installation location from sda to sda5. Check: https://www.scientificlinux.org/distributions/6x/installing/upgrade-guide-full.html - Installation used the default settings such as a swap partition, a boot partition and a home partition between others, with enough memory. Check: https://www.scientificlinux.org/distributions/6x/installing/install-guide-full.html

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what is installed on which partition (Linux, Windows)? With XP you could use grub4dos - I am not sure about Windows7 though.

Comment: I am not familiar with SL but it sounds like you need to install your boot loader in MBR (Master boot record). Try 'Upgrade boot loader' and search for option to install it in MBR.

Comment: @botzko Thats a good suggestion but I have indeed marked the option of installing the boot loader under the MBR during the installation process. I did try other options when tried to install it again with no luck either...

Comment: @Ini you can check solution from jasonwryan link. Just start some live cd and follow the instructions.
P.S. How many HDDs are in your laptop?

Comment: @botzko I believe there is only one but I need to make sure of it. Why do you think this could be a matter of importance?